# Adding a watermark to title page with openxml

Tags: c#, cpu-word, openxml-sdk, watermark

I am using C# and the Open XML SDK to create a watermark in a Word document. This works fine apart from one thing - the first page doesn't show the watermark.

I believe this is due to the Header and Footer setting "Different First Page" being ticked in the document.

In terms of what I have tried - I have used the add watermark code and applied it to the relevant header.xml file that is produced as part of the documents contents but it had the effect of showing an additional watermark on the subsequent pages rather than first.

I am struggling to find anything online to help with this. Can anybody please shed light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by me not creating the 3 necessary header files for each enum type. It needs HeaderPart and HeaderReference set. Section Properties should be updated for thi.

[Microsoft documentation of Header enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.headerfootervalues?view=openxml-2.8.1)